# How to reverse engineer a PostGIS enabled database with Eclipse Hibernate Tools?

Tags: eclipse, hibernate, reverse-engineering, postgis, hibernate-spatial

This is my set up:

- PostgreSQL 9.3
- PostGIS 2.1.4
- Eclipse Mars
- Hibernate Tools 5.0
- Hibernate Spatial <del>4.3</del> 5.0

I also added `postgis-jdbc.jar` and `jts.jar` to the build path.

The `.cfg.xml` file opens with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">the_pass</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/the_db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">me</property>
    <property name="hibernate.default_schema">the_schema</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect"</property>
    <!-- "Import" the mapping resources here -->
```

In the `reveng.xml` file, the tables including geometry type fields are explicitly declared with `table-filter` elements:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    [...]
    <table-filter match-name="coordinates"></table-filter>
    <table-filter match-name="polygon"></table-filter>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```

The Hibernate code generation configuration is creating POJOs with this kind of properties and methods for geometry type fields:

```
private Serializable geom;

public Serializable getGeom() {
        return this.geom;
}

public void setGeom(Serializable geom) {
        this.geom = geom;
}
```

In the [Hibernate Spatial tutorial](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/documentation/02-Tutorial/01-tutorial4/), geometry fields are mapped to JTS types, such as (`com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point`). Therefore with this code it is not possible to follow the mechanisms proposed there to retrieve/update spatial fields.

Is it possible to tweak the Hibernate configuration somehow for it to generate mappings from spatial fields to JTS types? Or must these generated `Serializable` properties be used instead?

**Update**: Bakc [at the Hibernate Spatial mail list I am told](http://www.hibernatespatial.org/pipermail/hibernatespatial-users/2016-February/000930.html) I should have matching versions of Hibernate Spatial and Hibernate. Hibernate Spatial 5.0.7 is not available from the official web site, but I found it elsewhere. Even with these matching version I am getting `Serializable` type fields in the generated POJOs.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the meta tag even in your hibernate.reveng.xml like this:

```
    <table name="position_vehicle" schema="public">
    <primary-key>
        <generator class="sequence">
            <param name="sequence">position_vehicle_id_seq</param>
        </generator>
        <key-column name="id"/>
    </primary-key>
    <column name="position">
        <meta attribute="use-in-tostring">true</meta>
        <meta attribute="property-type">com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Geometry</meta>
    </column>
</table>
```

I am using hibernate tools 5.0.0 and hibernate spatial 5.1.0.
For additional information about meta tags go to [hibernate meta](https://docs.jboss.org/tools/latest/en/hibernatetools/html/codegen.html)